# ds389 [FreeIPA] : Exporting Schema?

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, freeipa, unboundid

Are there any tools out there to export the data and along with schema from a 389 directory server ?

So far, I tried the db2ldif which do not export the entire schema. (looks like or may be I am wrong here..)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are implying by export the data and along with schema.

For the schema, Most LDAP servers support the [SubschemaSubentry](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SubschemaSubentry) entry within the rootDSE of the server to allow obtaining information about the schema.

You can normally use an [LDAP Query For Schema](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20For%20Schema) and save to a file.

There are several LDAP browsers out there that allow this to be done within a GUI. (I like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) )

Comment: Thanks for the input.